# The requested URL /practice/public/admin was not found on this server

Tags: php, linux, url, laravel-5, routes

My url i.e. localhost/practice laravel's default method 'welcome' working perfectly which is in routes.php file

```
Route::get('/', function () { 
    return view('welcome'); 
    }
);
```

whereas in case if just wants to access anything on the same url via routes.php say eg:

```
Route::get('/admin', function () {
    //return view('welcome'); 
    return "Admin URL."; 
    }
);
```

Then the following below mentioned error occurs.

> The requested URL /practice/public/admin was not found on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.23 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80 Not Found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try calling the following url in your case

```
localhost/practice/public/index.php/admin
```

maybe some route issue..